# sqlite3, how can I look in all columns of an index in one time?

Tags: sqlite

I have a table where 10 columns of it are used as tags (named TAG01, ..., TAG10). I made an index of these 10 columns.

so, if I want to fetch all rows with the word "happynewyear2015" in TAG01 I query this :

```
SELECT * FROM mytable INDEXED BY myindex WHERE TAG01=='happynewyear2015';
```

so, if "happynewyear2015" is in TAG02, or any other TAGXX but TAG01, the query above will not return the row. I'm looking for a query like :

```
SELECT * FROM mytable INDEXED BY myindex WHERE * =='happynewyear2015';
```

there is any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ten-column index would be useful only if you do searches on *all* the fields, like this:

```
... WHERE TAG01 = '...' AND TAG02 = '...' AND ...
```

You should store the tags in a separate table, with one row per tag, so that you get a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE ID IN (SELECT MyTableID
             FROM TagsTable
             WHERE Tag = 'happynewyear2015')
```

Comment: that was my first idea when I didn't know anything about indexing (I use sqlite since two days only). I shall think a little about your suggestion. THX

Comment: looks like it does the job well! I shall select your answer. THX CL.